# Async doInBackground will crash, and force close

Tags: java, android, json, eclipse, android-asynctask

My application will force crash sometimes and following is the error

```
    01-05 14:55:40.341: E/AndroidRuntime(16526): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
    01-05 14:55:40.341: E/AndroidRuntime(16526): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error 
    occured while executing doInBackground()
    01-05 14:55:40.341: E/AndroidRuntime(16526): at   
    android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
    01-05 14:55:40.341: E/AndroidRuntime(16526):    at 
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
    01-05 14:55:40.341: E/AndroidRuntime(16526):    at
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
    01-05 14:55:40.341: E/AndroidRuntime(16526):    at  
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
    01-05 14:55:40.341: E/AndroidRuntime(16526):    at  
    android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
    01-05 14:55:40.341: E/AndroidRuntime(16526):    at 
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    01-05 14:55:40.341: E/AndroidRuntime(16526):    at 
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    01-05 14:55:40.341: E/AndroidRuntime(16526):    at  
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
    01-05 14:55:40.341: E/AndroidRuntime(16526): Caused by: 
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    01-05 14:55:40.341: E/AndroidRuntime(16526):    at   

    com.example.splashscreentwo.EmployeePayslip$LoadAllPayslip.doInBackground
    (EmployeePayslip.java:152)
    01-05 14:55:40.341: E/AndroidRuntime(16526):    at  
    com.example.splashscreentwo.EmployeePayslip$LoadAllPayslip.doInBackground
    (EmployeePayslip.java:1)
    01-05 14:55:40.341: E/AndroidRuntime(16526):    at  
    android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    01-05 14:55:40.341: E/AndroidRuntime(16526):    at 
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
```

And this is the following code for the page;

```
    package com.example.splashscreentwo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class EmployeePayslip extends Activity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONArray payslip = null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> payslipList;

    // url to get all fulltime employees list
    private static String url_payslip = "http://rollit.sg/FYP/ExportPayslip.php";

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PAYSLIP = "payslip";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_PAYSLIPNO = "payslipno";
    private static final String TAG_NETSALARY = "netsalary";
    private static final String TAG_ISSUEDATE = "issuedate";
    private static final String TAG_STARTOFPAYSLIP = "startofpayslip";
    private static final String TAG_ENDOFPAYSLIP = "endofpayslip";
    private static final String TAG_TYPEOFALLOWANCE = "typeofallowance";
    private static final String TAG_ALLOWANCEAMT = "allowanceamt";
    private static final String TAG_ALLOWANCEDATE = "allowancedate";
    private static final String TAG_AVAILABLEALLOWANCE = "availableallowance";
    private static final String TAG_TYPEOFDEDUCTION = "typeofdeduction";
    private static final String TAG_DEDUCTIONAMT = "deductionamt";
    private static final String TAG_DEDUCTIONDATE = "deductiondate";
    private static final String TAG_AGREEDOVERTIMERATE = "agreedovertimerate";
    private static final String TAG_OVERTIMERATE = "overtimerate";
    private static final String TAG_STARTOFOVERTIMEPERIOD = "startofovertimeperiod";
    private static final String TAG_ENDOFOVERTIMEPERIOD = "endofovertimeperiod";
    private static final String TAG_BASICSALARY = "basicsalary";
    private static final String TAG_EXTRAPAYMENT = "extrapayment";




    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.employeepayslip);




     payslipList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

     // Loading all fulltime employees in Background Thread
     new LoadAllPayslip().execute();


    }

    class LoadAllPayslip extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

       protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_payslip, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // fulltime employees found
                    // Getting Array of fulltime employees
                    payslip = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PAYSLIP);

                    // looping through All fulltime employees
                    for (int i = 0; i < payslip.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = payslip.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        final String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        final String payslipno = c.getString(TAG_PAYSLIPNO);
                        final String netsalary = c.getString(TAG_NETSALARY);
                        final String issuedate = c.getString(TAG_ISSUEDATE);
                        final String startofpayslip = c.getString(TAG_STARTOFPAYSLIP);
                        final String endofpayslip = c.getString(TAG_ENDOFPAYSLIP);
                        final String typeofallowance = c.getString(TAG_TYPEOFALLOWANCE);
                        final String allowanceamt = c.getString(TAG_ALLOWANCEAMT);
                        final String allowancedate = c.getString(TAG_ALLOWANCEDATE);
                        final String availableallowance = c.getString(TAG_AVAILABLEALLOWANCE);
                        final String typeofdeduction = c.getString(TAG_TYPEOFDEDUCTION);
                        final String deductionamt = c.getString(TAG_DEDUCTIONAMT);
                        final String deductiondate = c.getString(TAG_DEDUCTIONDATE);
                        final String agreedovertimerate = c.getString(TAG_AGREEDOVERTIMERATE);
                        final String overtimerate = c.getString(TAG_OVERTIMERATE);
                        final String startofovertimeperiod = c.getString(TAG_STARTOFOVERTIMEPERIOD);
                        final String endofovertimeperiod = c.getString(TAG_ENDOFOVERTIMEPERIOD);
                        final String basicsalary = c.getString(TAG_BASICSALARY);
                        final String extrapayment = c.getString(TAG_EXTRAPAYMENT);

                        ImageButton sendSMS= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.send);
                        Button sendEmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settings);

                        final String message = "Dear " + name + ", your payslip number is " + payslipno +" and your net salary for the period " + startofpayslip + " till " + 
                                  endofpayslip + " is "+  netsalary + " and it is issused on " + issuedate + ". According to the agreed overtime rate of " + agreedovertimerate + " from " + 
                                            startofovertimeperiod + " till " + endofovertimeperiod +  ", your net salary is calculated by adding your basic salary of " +
                                            basicsalary + " to your available allowance of " + typeofallowance + " of " + allowanceamt + " on " + allowancedate + ", and any other extra payment of" +
                                            extrapayment + " and deducting from " + typeofdeduction 
                                            + " of " + deductionamt + " on " + deductiondate + ". Your availabe allowance for this month is " + availableallowance + ". " ;
                       sendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                              @Override
                              public void onClick(View view) {

                                String phoneNo = "96545373";
                                sendSMS(phoneNo, message);     

                              }

                            private void sendSMS(String phoneNo, String message) {

                                SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                              ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(message);
                            sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNo, null, parts, null, null); 

                            }
                          });
                     // creating new HashMap
                    sendEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                         public void onClick(View view) {
                             String email = "oslhanzo@hotmail.com";
                         sendEmail(message, email);
                      }

                    private void sendEmail(String message, String email) {
                        Log.i("Send email", "");

                        String[] TO = {"oslhanzo@hotmail.com"};
                        String[] CC = {"mcmohd@gmail.com"};
                        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
                        emailIntent.setType("text/plain");


                        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
                        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
                        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Payslip for period " + startofpayslip + " till " + endofpayslip);
                        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

                        try {
                           startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
                           Log.i("Finished sending email...", "");
                        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                           Toast.makeText(EmployeePayslip.this, 
                           "There is no email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                     }
                    });

                    }
                } else {
                    // no fulltime employee found
                    // Launch Add New employee Activity
                 //   Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    //        NewProductActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                 //   i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                  //  startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }


    }
         }
```

The application is working fine if i did not add this part into the code;

```
    sendEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                     public void onClick(View view) {
                         String email = "oslhanzo@hotmail.com";
                     sendEmail(message, email);
                  }

                private void sendEmail(String message, String email) {
                    Log.i("Send email", "");

                    String[] TO = {"oslhanzo@hotmail.com"};
                    String[] CC = {"mcmohd@gmail.com"};
                    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
                    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");


                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Payslip for period " + startofpayslip + " till " + endofpayslip);
                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

                    try {
                       startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
                       Log.i("Finished sending email...", "");
                    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                       Toast.makeText(EmployeePayslip.this, 
                       "There is no email client installed.",            
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                 }
                });
```

I dont know what is the reason for the crash, is it doInbackground couldnt handle too much task? Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: It seems sendEmail is Null, so make sure that R.id.settings is defined in your layout

Comment: Oh yes! I made a slight mistake of the name. That solved the problem, thanks alot mate! @mohamed_abdallah

Answer (score 0):

`sendEmail` is null since you made a mistake in the naming of `R.id.settings`

Answer (score 0):

You should not be accessing UI elements(Buttons) in doInBackground.

You should just set the onClickListener in onCreate itself.

in onCreate of the activity:

```
                  ImageButton sendSMS= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.send);
                    Button sendEmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settings);


                   sendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                          @Override
                          public void onClick(View view) {

                            String phoneNo = "96545373";
                            sendSMS(phoneNo, message);     

                          }

                        private void sendSMS(String phoneNo, String message) {

                            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                          ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(message);
                        sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNo, null, parts, null, null); 

                        }
                      });
                 // creating new HashMap
                sendEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                     public void onClick(View view) {
                         String email = "oslhanzo@hotmail.com";
                     sendEmail(message, email);
                  }

                private void sendEmail(String message, String email) {
                    Log.i("Send email", "");

                    String[] TO = {"oslhanzo@hotmail.com"};
                    String[] CC = {"mcmohd@gmail.com"};
                    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
                    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");


                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Payslip for period " + startofpayslip + " till " + endofpayslip);
                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

                    try {
                       startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
                       Log.i("Finished sending email...", "");
                    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                       Toast.makeText(EmployeePayslip.this, 
                       "There is no email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                 }
                });
```

Also declare `message` inside activity which will be accessible inside doInbackground so just set it:

```
 message = "Dear " + name + ", your payslip number is " + payslipno +" and your net salary for the period " + startofpayslip + " till " + 
                                  endofpayslip + " is "+  netsalary + " and it is issused on " + issuedate + ". According to the agreed overtime rate of " + agreedovertimerate + " from " + 
                                            startofovertimeperiod + " till " + endofovertimeperiod +  ", your net salary is calculated by adding your basic salary of " +
                                            basicsalary + " to your available allowance of " + typeofallowance + " of " + allowanceamt + " on " + allowancedate + ", and any other extra payment of" +
                                            extrapayment + " and deducting from " + typeofdeduction 
                                            + " of " + deductionamt + " on " + deductiondate + ". Your availabe allowance for this month is " + availableallowance + ". " ;
```

now the only possible problem will be if buttons are clicked before message value is set.

So in onclick event just check if message is not null then only send the message.